# How to set value in a nested Map using Lens

Tags: haskell, dictionary, haskell-lens

I have the following program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Control.Lens

data MyLabel = MyLabel { _label :: String } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data MyMap = MyMap { _vals :: Map.Map String MyLabel } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
makeLenses ''MyLabel
makeLenses ''MyMap

sample :: MyMap
sample = MyMap { _vals = Map.fromList [("foo", MyLabel "bar")] }
```

Now I'd like to know how to do a transformation `f` using lenses such that:

```
f sample "quux" == MyMap { _vals = Map.fromList [("foo", MyLabel "quux")] }
```

I learned that the function `at` from Lens library should be used to modify Maps, so I was trying to do things like this:

```
sample ^. vals & at "foo" . label .~ Just "quux"
```

But that produces an error message which is not very understandable for me. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `data` instead of `newtype` for this?

Comment: Yes, for better readability, it's extracted from a larger piece of code where I use more fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Control.Lens

data MyLabel =
  MyLabel { _label :: String } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data MyMap =
  MyMap { _vals :: Map.Map String MyLabel } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

makeLenses ''MyLabel
makeLenses ''MyMap

sample :: MyMap
sample =
  MyMap (Map.fromList [("foo", MyLabel "bar")])

main :: IO ()
main =
  print (sample & (vals . at "foo" . _Just . label .~ "quux"))
```

Remember that, when setting, you're trying to build a function of type `MyMap -> MyMap`. The way you do that is by chaining a bunch of optics together (`vals . at "foo" . _Just . label`) and then choosing a setter operation (`.~`). You can't mix and match a getter operation like `^.` with a setter operation like `.~`! So every setter more or less looks like this:

```
foo' = (optic1 . optic2 . optic3 . optic4) .~ value $ foo
--     _________this has type Foo -> Foo___________
```

And to improve readability we use `&`, the flipped version of `$`:

```
foo' = foo & (optic1 . optic2 . optic3 . optic4) .~ value
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. However, I am still getting a similar compile error message when I try to compile your code. What version of ghc/lens should I use for this to work? `Couldn't match type ‘IxValue (Map.Map String MyLabel)’ with ‘MyLabel’` ... `Couldn't match expected type ‘Index (Map.Map String MyLabel) with actual type ‘[Char]’ `

Comment: GHC 7.10, latest lens

Answer (score -1):

The problem was actually caused by cabal hell and cleaning up `~/.ghc` directory was necessary to make it work.